# Alternative to dir command to query a directory in C

Tags: c, dos, c89, turbo-c

I am trying to create a program where the user can add different path regex-s so that a specific set of operations on the files that match the regex.

I tried using `opendir()` of the dirent.h header file but soon realized that it does not use the concept of regex.

The `dir` command I am trying to emulate is

```
dir [regex] /b
```

I need the output in a (char) buffer**. Piping the output could be a solution but I am looking for a more efficient way to do it.

Is there any predefined function in the standard (C90) library or will we have to create our own implementation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207986/discussion-on-question-by-hello-world-alternative-to-dir-command-to-query-a-dire).

Comment: I am recommending you GLib.

Comment: Glib for  DOSBox?

Comment: If you are programming for DOS, use the *Find First File* and *Find Next File* functions.

Comment: Note that what `dir` takes is commonly known as a *glob,* not a *regex*.

Answer (score 1):

C does not know about [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)). They are [operating system](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) specific, usually provided by your [OS kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) (look however inside [GNU Hurd](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd.html) as an exception, and into [unikernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unikernel)). Read the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and forget, in 2020, about the obsolete [C89](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C#C89)  standard and [TurboC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Turbo_C). Consider trying some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) (such as [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) or [Debian](https://www.debian.org/) or others). Most of them provide [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) (or the non-[optimizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) [TinyCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) compiler) and are very developer-friendly. My recommendation: use GCC [as](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Choose a good enough [built automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (maybe [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)) with an appropriate [source-code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-code_editor) (such as GNU [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [vim](https://vim.org/) or [geany](https://www.geany.org/) or others). Learn [*how to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and use the [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/) debugger and the [`git`](https://git-scm.com/) version control tool.

[POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) does know about directories (it is an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) specification written in English,  also defining [regex(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/regex)). See [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), and read the [Linux man pages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/). And also the [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API).

On Linux, see [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html), [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html),  [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), [getcwd(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html), [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html), [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html), [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) etc etc; you could want to study the source code of a [Linux kernel](https://kernel.org/) and of some common C library for it, such as [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](https://musl-libc.org/). Budget for that several months full time of your efforts. They are [open source](https://opensource.org/licenses), so with some conditions you are allowed to study, improve and reuse their [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code). See also http://linuxfromscratch.org/

Notice also [popen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html). You probably don't want to use it and would prefer using more primitive [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) for their list on Linux). You could use a library like [Glib](https://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/) (from [GTK](https://gtk.org/)).

Remember that C programs (of the [freestanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) kind) could run on the bare metal (e.g. [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/)). In those cases, speaking of directories does not make any sense. See also [osdev.org](https://osdev.org/) for more, and observe that the [Linux kernel](https://kernel.org/) is written in C (with a tiny amount of assembler code).

[GrassHopper](https://www.academia.edu/download/50815623/DdF_94b.pdf) was an OS written mostly in C without any files or directories. See also old discussions archived on [tunes.org](http://tunes.org/) and [tccboot](https://github.com/seyko2/tccboot).

Comment: Could you share the download link for POSIX C90?

Comment: @HelloWorld: I don't think that POSIX C90 exist. The POSIX standard is an OS API above C.

Comment: Any regex library for C90?

Comment: @Hello World: POSIX has one. C90 does not

Comment: @Hello World: Download then install some Linux distribution such as [Debian](https://debian.org/). It is free (both libre and gratis) and runs on most PCs. Backup your precious data before installing any Linux distribution. Ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ for help if so needed

Comment: Actually I was looking for something like a library in Turbo C++. The same goes for the other answer you had posted yesterday. But I am pretty sure that it would help someone else at some point in the future. So please don't delete it.

Comment: OP is programming on Turbo C.  None of the advice you give is in any way relevant to that.

Comment: The main advice is to give up TurboC

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Your main advice is to use both a different toolchain and a different operating system.  That's not really an answer to OPs question; would be fine as a comment though.  OP probably has a reason for using the toolchain he uses.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `findfirst` to start querying a directory and then `findnext` to iterate.  The functions find all files in one directory matching a given pattern, so you possibly need to append `\*.*` to your directory name to list all files in that directory.

Refer to the Turbo C documentation for details.